# Como crear un JSON con Clases Padre y Hijo en c#

Tags: c#, arraylist

quisiera que me puedan ayudar a como crear una clase Padre con atributos de tipo Clase tal como muestro en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la siguiente imagen tengo una clase padre y esa clase tiene atributos de tipo Clase que tiene sus atributos.

```
public class YARD
{

    public int KVJE { get; set; }

    public string KENT_DEPO { get; set; }

    public string YARDID { get; set; }

    public string YARD2 { get; set; }

    public string ACTION { get; set; }

    public List<DEPOTORDER> DEPOTORDER { get; set; }
```

}

Intente crearlo como Lista y luego agregarle datos , pero me trae como null.

Comment: Serializar y de-serializar son Case Sensitive. Puedes utilizar el atributo `[JsonProperty("nombrePropiedadComoEnElJSON")]` en la parte superior de las propiedades de la clase.

Comment: Donde esta la parte en que tratas de llenar los datos que mencionas? Podrías publicarlo?